# $X_n \overset{p}{\to} X$ and $X_n$ independent implies $X$ almost surely constant

Tags: probability

I'm quite confused with the meaning of "almost surely a constant". Does this mean that $P(X = c) = 1$?

I don't really understand how we can insert the independence condition into the argument.

Comment: "I don't really understand how we can insert the independence condition into the argument" To get you an idea, consider the event $$A_x=\limsup\{X_n\leqslant x\}$$ for some given $x$. What can you say about $P(A_x)$, *using the fact that $(X_n)$ is independent*?

Comment: @Surb "there are lots sequence (Xn) s.t. Xn→X in probability but X is not constant a.s." When the sequence $(X_n)$ is independent? Such as?

Comment: @Did : After written this comment, I was thinking that I may be wrong (as you seems to confirm). Thank you :-)